# Retroactively set new ManyToManyField default values to existing model

Tags: python, django, model

I have a Django model (called `BiomSearchJob`) which is currently live and I want to add a new many-to-many relation to make the system more customizable for the user. Previously, users can submit a job without specifying a set of `TaxonomyLevelChoices` but to add more features to the system, users should now be able to select their own taxonomy levels.

Here's the model:

```
class TaxonomyLevelChoice(models.Model):
    taxon_level = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Taxonomy Chart Level", max_length=60)
    taxon_level_proper_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.taxon_level_proper_name

class BiomSearchJob(models.Model):
    ...
    # The new many-to-many relation
    taxonomy_levels = models.ManyToManyField(
        'TaxonomyLevelChoice', blank=False, max_length=3,
        default=["phylum", "class", "genus"])

    name = models.CharField(
        null=False, blank=False, max_length=100, default="Unnamed Job",
        validators=[alphanumeric_spaces])
    ...
```

Currently, all existing `BiomSearchJobs` implicitly have the three taxonomy levels listed in the `default=` term (which are not user-selectable) and hence are all the same in the database. After running `migrate`, I find that the previous jobs don't immediately have the three taxonomy level relations, they only return an empty set upon calling `job.taxonomy_levels.all()` (if `job` were an instance of `BiomSearchJob`).

Is there a way to retroactively add this relationship without manually going through everything? Ideally, by just running `migrate` I would like the existing `BiomSearchJobs` to have `phylum`, `class`, and `genus` listed in the `taxonomy_levels` attribute.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're looking for a data migration, which is a migration allowing for data-only changes over the database.

You can create it this way:

```
python manage.py makemigrations <your app> --name=retroactively_add_levels
```

Then insert this code into the migration file just created:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations


def add_taxonomy_levels(apps, schema_editor):
    BiomSearchJob = apps.get_model('<your app>', 'BiomSearchJob')
    TaxonomyLevelChoice = apps.get_model('<your app>', 'TaxonomyLevelChoice')
    for job in BiomSearchJob.objects.all():
        for choice in TaxonomyLevelChoice.objects.filter(taxon_level_proper_name__in=["phylum", "class", "genus"]):
            job.taxonomy_levels.add(choice)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

   dependencies = []

operations = [
    migrations.RunPython(add_taxonomy_levels, reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop)
]
```

It works pretty much as an SQL query would do but it leverages on Django ORM.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach cannot work, as you implicitly want to make a query on an instance property: Django can't guess that.

From [Django's Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#default), default can be a function, while

> For fields like ForeignKey that map to model instances, defaults should be the value of the field they reference (pk unless to_field is set) instead of model instances.

So.... Either you pass a PK (eg ID) array, either you use a function to get queryset.

```
class TaxonomyLevelChoice(models.Model):
    taxon_level = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Taxonomy Chart Level", max_length=60)
    taxon_level_proper_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.taxon_level_proper_name

def get_default_taxonomy_levels():
    ...
    return YourQuerySet


class BiomSearchJob(models.Model):
    ...
    # The new many-to-many relation
    taxonomy_levels = models.ManyToManyField(
        'TaxonomyLevelChoice', blank=False, max_length=3,
        default=get_taxonomy_levels_default)

    name = models.CharField(
        null=False, blank=False, max_length=100, default="Unnamed Job",
        validators=[alphanumeric_spaces])
    ...
```

I guess you will have migration issues if you migrate before `TaxonomyLevelChoice` instances has not been created.

I'd go for the function solution due to previous sentence, with some pseudo cache method though, as making a query each time you create `BiomSearchJob` is not an acceptable solution.

I'd do:

```
DEFAULT_TAXONOMY_LEVELS = None

def get_default_taxonomy_levels():
    if DEFAULT_TAXONOMY_LEVELS:
        return DEFAULT_TAXONOMY_LEVELS
    ...
    DEFAULT_TAXONOMY_LEVELS = YourQuerySet
    return YourQuerySet
```

Edit: As the question is to retro-actively set a Many to Many default value, I'd suggest a command to do so on existing instances, as I don't think migration will handle that for you.